# ngComponentOutlet or ndcDynamicComponent not working with angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

hello I am really confused that why it is not working its very simple still i am getting issue.
I am getting blank output & my components has some data which is getting updated if i directly call it with its selector.

here is my code.

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeatSealComponent } from './heat-seal/heat-seal.component';
import { PrinterComponent } from './printer/printer.component';
import { DynamicModule } from 'ng-dynamic-component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeatSealComponent,
    PrinterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    [DynamicModule],
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="dumm"></ng-container>
<ndc-dynamic [ndcDynamicComponent]="dumm"></ndc-dynamic>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeatSealComponent } from './heat-seal/heat-seal.component';
import { PrinterComponent } from './printer/printer.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'dynamic-loading';
  dumm = HeatSealComponent;

  ngOnInit() {

    // this.myContent = {name:'nope'};
  }
}
```

Comment: The import of ```[DynamicModule]``` looks wrong - it should be just DynamicModule without additional brackets as it is  already an element of imports array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to declare the components in the **EntryComponents** in the **my module** file.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeatSealComponent } from './heat-seal/heat-seal.component';
import { PrinterComponent } from './printer/printer.component';
import { DynamicModule } from 'ng-dynamic-component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeatSealComponent,
    PrinterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    [DynamicModule],
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [HeatSealComponent, PrinterComponent], // ADD THIS
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What is DynamicComponent1 and DynamicComponent2?

Comment: @ShreyanshAgarwal those are the components which we want to load dynamically using  ngComponentOutlet or ndcDynamicComponent. I have replaced those names with the names in my code so it will be easy to understand.